# Inno Setup Skip "Select Components" page when /Type command-line parameter is specified

Tags: inno-setup

I have an Inno setup installer where I am setting the setup type via the command line like so, `/TYPE=full`. When I do this the correct type is selected. What I would like to do is take it one step further and disable option to change the type. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Do you want to skip the "Setup Type" page of an existing installer? Or do you want to modify your own installer in a way that when the type is specified on the command line, the "Setup Type" page is skipped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`ShouldSkipPage` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents) to skip the "Select Components" page when the `/TYPE` command-line parameter is specified:

```pascal
[Code]

function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (PageID = wpSelectComponents) and (ExpandConstant('{param:TYPE}') <> '');
end;
```