# Discard the /TYPE and /COMPONENTS parameter on upgrade

Tags: inno-setup

In case of an upgrade / re-installation, is there a way to discard the `/TYPE` and `/COMPONENTS` parameter value passed on the command line to the installer and instead use the previously used values ?
I can read the values used earlier from Registry (or alternatively make out the details based on existence of files assuming they have not been manually altered)

I have read the following threads and can disable the "Select Components" page in UI mode

1. [Inno Setup Skip "Select Components" page when /Type command-line parameter is specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711005/inno-setup-skip-select-components-page-when-type-command-line-parameter-is-sp)
2. [InnoSetup: Disable components page on upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529370/innosetup-disable-components-page-on-upgrade)

However, if the aforesaid parameters are passed from command line, they seem to override the defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot discard them.

What you can do is to check if those parameters were provided and if they were:

- Re-launch the installer without them (show below), or
- Read the previously selected type and components from registry and re-set the controls accordingly.

---

### Re-launching the installer without `/TYPE=` and `/COMPONENTS=`

```pascal
const
  UninstallKey =
    'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\' +
    '{#SetupSetting("AppId")}_is1';

function IsUpgrade: Boolean;
var
  Value: string;
begin
  Result :=
    (RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, UninstallKey, 'UninstallString', Value) or
     RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, UninstallKey, 'UninstallString', Value)) and
    (Value <> '');
end;

function ShellExecute(hwnd: HWND; lpOperation: string; lpFile: string;
  lpParameters: string; lpDirectory: string; nShowCmd: Integer): THandle;
  external 'ShellExecuteW@shell32.dll stdcall';
  
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  Params, S: string;
  Relaunch: Boolean;
  I, RetVal: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;

  if IsUpgrade then
  begin
    Relaunch := False;
    // Collect current instance parameters
    for I := 1 to ParamCount do
    begin
      S := ParamStr(I);
      if (CompareText(Copy(S, 1, 7), '/TYPES=') = 0) or
         (CompareText(Copy(S, 1, 12), '/COMPONENTS=') = 0) then
      begin
        Log(Format('Will re-launch due to %s', [S]));
        Relaunch := True;
      end
        else
      begin
        // Unique log file name for the child instance
        if CompareText(Copy(S, 1, 5), '/LOG=') = 0 then
        begin
          S := S + '-sub';
        end;
        // Do not pass our /SL5 switch
        // This should not be needed since Inno Setup 6.2,
        // see https://groups.google.com/g/innosetup/c/pDSbgD8nbxI
        if CompareText(Copy(S, 1, 5), '/SL5=') <> 0 then
        begin
          Params := Params + AddQuotes(S) + ' ';
        end;
      end;
    end;

    if not Relaunch then
    begin
      Log('No need to re-launch');
    end
      else
    begin
     Log(Format('Re-launching setup with parameters [%s]', [Params]));
      RetVal :=
        ShellExecute(0, '', ExpandConstant('{srcexe}'), Params, '', SW_SHOW);
      Log(Format('Re-launching setup returned [%d]', [RetVal]));
      Result := (RetVal > 32);
      // if re-launching of this setup succeeded, then...
      if Result then
      begin
        Log('Re-launching succeeded');
        // exit this setup instance
        Result := False;
      end
        else
      begin
        Log(Format('Elevation failed [%s]', [SysErrorMessage(RetVal)]));
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The code is for Unicode version of Inno Setup (the only version as of Inno Setup 6).

The code can be further improved to keep the master installer waiting for the child installer to complete. What can make a difference, particularly if the installer is executed by some automatic deployment process.